# Body fat and abs

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training, body-fat, abdominals

I have a 9.2% body fat ,1.80 m and 81 kg and still I have enough fat on my abs...I diet and workout hard I always check to have enough proteins,calories,etc every day.I had 5 months ago 19% body fat and I am thinking maybe that is the problem,maybe I lost body fat too fast? Or am I doing something wrong?I have a 7 day training program and I work my abs 2 day a week and my hips another 2 days a week.

Comment: How did you measure your body-fat?

Comment: Went to a pharmacy and asked the pharmacist to measure my body fat,and he measured it on a strange big scale.Asked me to place my middle or index fingers(i don't remember) on 2 pipes of the scale.

Comment: Sounds like it was a standard electrical resistance scan. That means nothing and it highly dependant on your hydration level. I recommend you type in "belly fat" into the search box on the top right and read through the millions of questions/answers.

Comment: Most of them say you need diet, exercise and be careful with sugar intake.I really am paying attention on all of these and still I can see my abs but I have a layer of fat skin on it that I cannot get rid of.Must I give it more time to disappear maybe?

Comment: Have you considered you might not have visible abs because they aren't developed. They can't develop without a calorie surplus to provide them with the protein for growth.

Comment: you'll absolutely still have fat on your abs w/ a bodyfat % in the 9s, but lower bodyfat % doesn't necessarily equate to more cut up abs; I'd look into your ab routine before thinking about further dieting.  If you want to get an idea of what kind of variation bodyfat % has on appearance, this might help: http://www.draftexpress.com/nba-pre-draft-measurements/.  You'll see guys that don't look in that good of shape w/ respectable bodyfat %s, guys that look way more ripped w/ similar bodyfat %s, and guys with super low bodyfat %s that don't look buff at all, just skinny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quit the whole body fat mentality.

This advice of mine is really generic but you can take some benefits from it.

One of the main reason could be that you're dieting wrong, or as someone suggested your abs are underdeveloped. Or you could be genetically prone to lose belly fat later than the other regions of your body ( and with this there's nothing you can do ).

You're basically asking if you're doing something wrong. Probably even your training regimen could be flawed.

High volumes of training during these phases are detrimental.

I advice you to go back to a bulking phase a study a better plan for next dieting window.

Comment: Meh, I guess you are right I like how I developed myself until now the fat on the belly was my only problem in rest I am very happy of myself

Answer (score 2):

Unless you get a dexa scan or similar things conducted, bodyfat measure is at best something that can be done with, i dont know, a 5-10% deviation.

You are likely not sub-10% bodyfat or even remotely close given your own description of your stomach. Either that, or you abs are widely underdeveloped.

Comment: I agree, with the weight like that and body fat percentage that low your abs should start to resemble a washboard. I think you are not estimating you BFP correctly. A. Aragon in his book "Lean Muscle Diet" says you can expect 1-2% body fat loss per month with proper nutrition and exercise. While 2% is within your decline rate, i would always lean to a more conservative side of equation. I'd find a good nutritionist or a coach and have him measure your BFP with body fat caliper. In proper hands it is a  precise instrument.

Comment: What is the most efficient and precise way to measure the body fat?

Comment: 5-10% deviation is a little bit absurd

Comment: Absurd? Yes, that's why they're useless. You're better off looking at estimated pictures of people with different bodyfat percentage(from dexa scans) and compare by eyesight.